# Legendre symbol $ p ≡ 5 \mod 8$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I need to prove:
If $p$ is a prime number congruent to $5 \mod 8$, and $\left(\frac np\right)= 1$, then

either $ [n^{(p+3)/8}] ^2 ≡  n\bmod p$

or   $ [n^{(p+3)/8}((p-1)/2)! ]^2 ≡  n\bmod p$

I am not really sure how to proceed, although I have tried checking the cases $n= 1$ and $n = -1$, I have also tried various things with the definition of a Legendre symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue as follows.

We know that $n$ is a quadratic residue.
The question is whether $n$ is a quartic residue or not.

- Assume first that $n\equiv a^4\pmod p$ for some $a$ coprime to $p$. By Little Fermat we can deduce that
  $$1\equiv a^{p-1}\equiv n^{(p-1)/4}\pmod p.$$
  Multiplying this congruence by $n$ gives
  $$
  n^{(p+3)/4}\equiv n\pmod p.
  $$
  As $k=(p+3)/8$ is an integer, this means that $(n^k)^2\equiv n$ in line with the first alternative.
- If $n$ is a modular square but **not** a modular fourth power, then I first claim that $-n$ will be a fourth power modulo $p$. This is because $-1$ is known to be a quadratic residue. But as $p\not\equiv 1\pmod 8$ there are no elements of order $8$, and consequently $-1$ cannot be a fourth power. The claim follows from this because the quotient group of quadratic residues modulo quartic residues is cyclic of order two (this holds for all $p\equiv1\pmod4$). The result of the previous bullet thus implies the congruence
  $$
  (-n)^{(p+3)/4}\equiv -n\pmod p. 
  $$
  Here $(p+3)/4$ is even, so this reads
  $$
  n^{(p+3)/4}\equiv -n\pmod p.\qquad(*)
  $$
- Let $u$ be the residue class of $((p-1)/2)!$. Because $p\equiv1\pmod4$ it follows from Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$, that $u^2\equiv-1\pmod p$. This allows us to rewrite congruence $(*)$ in the form
  $$[u n^{(p+3)/8}]^2\equiv n^{(p+3)/4}u^2\equiv (-n)\cdot (-1)=n\pmod p,$$
  which is exactly what the second alternative says.

Comment: yes, you are correct about the typo. I am not good with MathJax on here.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about the fix @user2782067. Don't worry. You'll get the hang of it quickly enough.